# Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог, перетаскивая layout за края, менять его размер?

Tags: android

У меня возникла проблема, которую я описал выше: мне нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог напрямую (своими пальцами) изменять размер layouta. (В моем случае я помещаю  EditText с android:inputType="textMultiLine" в CardView). Искал подобные вопросы, и наткнулся только на создание Виджетов с android:resizeMode. Но я так понял, что их нельзя поместить просто в своё приложение. Пример того, что является целью:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. То есть изначально имеется какой-то размер по умолчанию, и пользователь, двигая за края, изменяет размер этого layout(а).Как можно это реализовать? Спасибо.

Comment: По идее надо что-то типа слушателя тача вешать на, наверное, родителя целевой вьюхи и в этом слушателе по нужной вам логике высчитывать новые параметры для целевой вьюхи и программно их назначать.